# Increase height of div according to content

Tags: html, css

I have the following div, but it wont increase in size according to the content.

```
<div style="width:250px;border-radius:4px; background:#374953;padding:10px; font-weight:200; clear:both"> <img src="http://li.zoocdn.com/6ac9972d726687d35e8e1c25d2d0a23beaa2ea43_150_113.jpg" width="80" style="float:left; margin-right:10px;" />
  <h2 style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#fff; margin-top:0px; font-weight:200">2 Bedroom Property For Sale</h2>
  <h3 style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#fff; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; font-weight:200">&pound;1,234,567</h3>
</div>
```

I've added clear:both to the container div but no change.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CFwmh/

Comment: I would suggest keeping CSS and HTML separate.

Comment: It's becuase of your floated items/s. See my answer for the correct solution

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you have a floating `img` inside a `div`, and floating elements don't affect the dimensions of their containers (as you would've maybe expected).

Problem is solved with setting the [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) of the containing the div:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

### [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/CFwmh/1/)

---

Also, please consider to stop using inline styles and use [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/css) files.

Comment: probably good to explain what OP's problem was and why this fixes it

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

before end of last div

```
<div style="width:250px;border-radius:4px; background:#374953;padding:10px; font-weight:200; clear:both"> <img src="http://li.zoocdn.com/6ac9972d726687d35e8e1c25d2d0a23beaa2ea43_150_113.jpg" width="80" style="float:left; margin-right:10px;" />
      <h2 style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#fff; margin-top:0px; font-weight:200">2 Bedroom Property For Sale</h2>
      <h3 style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#fff; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; font-weight:200">&pound;1,234,567</h3>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What did you change? Please provide context for your answer, and a working Fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is known as the 'clearfix problem'. Most browsers do not take floating children into account when calculating an elemnts height.

There is plenty of information out there about this. This might be a good starting point: [What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)

In your case, you can solve this in 2 ways.

**Method 1:**
add an none floating elemnt as a last child into your div, and give it a style of `clear: both;` Something like this:

```
<div> 
  <img/>
  <h2>2 Bedroom Property For Sale</h2>
  <h3>&pound;1,234,567</h3>
  <div style='clear:both;'></div>
</div>
```

The disadvantage of this method is that you are actually adding markup, just for the purpose of styling, which is considered bad practice. That is why i would go for method 2.

**Method 2:**
Make the parent div self clearing. This can be done by adding `overflow:hidden;`to it as suggested, but that my produce unwanted results. There are cases where you may want overflow, but still want to clear the div. That is why I have a `clearfix`class in my standard stylesheet. It looks like this:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
  zoom: 1;
}
```

And you just need to apply it to the div like this:

```
    <div class='clearfix'> 
      <img/>
      <h2>2 Bedroom Property For Sale</h2>
      <h3>&pound;1,234,567</h3>
    </div>
```

This is just an example of a clearfix class, there are many different ones out there. Yhis one seems to work fine for me however.

And an example demonstrating both techniques: http://jsfiddle.net/LGvgj/

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have floated items. `clear` the last item.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/CFwmh/2/

In this case it's `h3`

```
h3 {
    clear: both;
}
```